# After update classpath 3.5.0. to 3.5.1

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, gradlew, android-studio-3.5.1

Upgrade Gradle build tools to the latest version then this issue occurs. Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ': classpath'.

> Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1.
>        Required by:
>            project :
>   Could not resolve com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.1.
>   Could not get resource 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.1/gradle-3.5.1.pom'.
>   Could not HEAD 'https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/3.5.1/gradle-3.5.1.pom'.
>   Remote host closed connection during handshake

Comment: What is your Error.? Please Explain more Details

Comment: @BADSHAH this message every time generate when i'm upgrade it.

Comment: Please Give me a Project-level build.gradle Screen Short

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the possible reason,

1) Check your internet connection, if it works then,

2) Check that your firewall, because if some of the `Google Service` blocks at that time also you get an exception.

3) Invalid cache and restart Android Studio.

Hops this helps.

Comment: Thanks, It's really helping me. My service provider blocks some website so this issue happen.

Comment: After updating AndroidStudio 3.5.3. Project is not building,Could you please help me on this, My Question -- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60221000/org-gradle-internal-exceptions-locationawareexception-org-gradle-api-projectco

Answer (score 0):

Try this  in Android Studio

```
Settings -> Build -> Gradle -> Android Studio -> Enable embedded maven repository
```

Answer (score 0):

In app level gradle file, add following

```
repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solved this error in our school where we used network "proxy" settings. The error is always [Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.] from old version of Android Studio SDK even the new one 3.6.1. Below are the steps I made and hope it will be of great help to you guys:
1. Check your Network Settings -> Proxy -> Use a Proxy Server (TURN IT OFF)
2. Check Control Panel\Network and Internet\Network Connections -> Ethernet Properties -> IPV4 Properties -> Change to obtained (or you set it with your common network IP)
3. Open the file gradle.properties location C:\Users\.gradle\  and remove all the settings related to "proxy" which makes the Android error in classpath.
Thats it.